# Spring query creation by method names - order by static number?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring `CrudRepository` with sql queries by method name.

I'd like to create a `.. WHERE age >= 18` static select statement. Spring supports the `GreaterThan` keyword.

But how can I integrate a static number, eg to fetch only adult users:

This does not work:
`public User findByAgeGreaterThan17();`

Comment: Post your code you have tried..!!

Comment: I guess the 17 is a typo and you just have findByAgeGreaterThan(int age)

Comment: No I'd like to implement a fixed method that does not take a variable age, but just has the static `age > 17` in the method name somehow. If possible at all.

Comment: Add a method and put a `@Query` annotation on it. That is, afaik, the only way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the `@Query` annotation and declare the query manually:

```
interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {

  @Query("select p from Person p where person.age >= 18")
  List<Person> findAdults();
}
```